# Rails Multiple Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, associations

I'm having trouble setting up my associations. I'm trying to set up `Courses` to have different `Prices` depending on the `Season` and amount of `alumns`. It gets even more complicated when `Seasons` have different date ranges for the same `Season`, like for instance the first `Season` is from 12/24/2014 to 12/31/2014 but also from 01/07/2015 to 01/14/2015. For this I created another model `Season_dates`.

I can't figure out how to set up my associations, here's what I have got so far:

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :season_dates
 has_many :prices, through: :season_dates
end

class SeasonDate < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :price
 belongs_to :seasons
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :course
 has_many :season_dates
 has_many :seasons, through: :season_dates

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :season_dates
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :prices
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @price do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.fields_for :couse do |course_f| %>
  <%= course_f.label :course %><br>
  <%= course_f.collection_select :course_id, Course.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :alumn %><br>
 <%= f.number_field :alumn, in: 1...11, step: 1, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.fields_for :season_date do |season_f| %>
  <%= season_f.label :season %><br>
  <%= season_f.select :season_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Season.all, :id, :name), {}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
 <% end %>
</div>
<div class="field form-group">
 <%= f.label :price %><br>
 <%= f.number_field :price, in: 0.01..999.99, step: 0.01, placeholder: "0.00€", class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-default' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I want to be able to call `price.season.name` or `price.course.name`. I'm not sure how to proceed, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use include and through relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be complicating the scenario a bit. Is there a reason that `SeasonDate` is its own class?  Is there a way you can model like this?

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :courses

  # I would have on this model the attributes of from_date and
  # to_date removing the need for a SeasonDate class

end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :season

  # You might need to model this as a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship
  # with a Season if a Course can belong to many seasons

end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :season

end
```

These models would give you methods such as:

```
@season.courses # would return all courses in a particular season
@price.season.name
@price.course.name
@course.prices # would return all prices associated with a particular course
```

If you do go for the habtm association, meaning a course can belong to many seasons, you could do something like this (guessing at your price attribute names) in your views.

```
<%= @course.name %>
<% @course.prices.each do |price| %>
 <%= price.season.name %> : <%= price.price_in_dollars %>
<% end
```

This would allow you to iterate over all prices for a course and display which season they are applicable for so each person can find the best price for them.

Comment: You were right I was complicating too much. My problem was with strong parameters, not passing the right model's id. Thank you for your answer It helped me a lot.